# iOS 9 issue: collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint

Tags: ios9

My app has the error with iOS9:

when I use the method:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:self.collectionView.contentOffset];
```

At iOS7/iOS8, `path = 547 - 0`

But iOS9, `path = 546 - 36`

so I get a different section

I don't know why??

Answer (score 0):

Does your app support a RightToLeft languages? (Arabic/Hebrew)

If so, the reason for your bug can be found here:
[UICollectionView iOS 9 issue on project with RTL languages support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33130331/uicollectionview-ios-9-issue-on-project-with-rtl-languages-support)

It's related to Apple new RTL support in iOS 9.
The bug has been reported to Apple.